# Woocommerce add upsells in database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add some upsells and crosssell products in woocommerce.
The last thing i want to do is to add everything manually, so created
query with random selected products and came up with this:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES(DEFAULT, product_id, '_crosssell_ids', 'a:3:{i:0;s:3:"crosssell_product_id";i:1;s:3:"crosssell_product_id";i:2;s:3:"crosssell_product_id";}');
```

But it is not being shown under the product. Is there any flag that indicates
whether this specific product has or not the upsell/crosssell associated?
Is there any other way to add crosssale/upsell products?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with a query but here is php code to set the cross sells.  My importer adds them this way.

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, [13, 14], '_crosssell_ids');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_crosssell_ids', [13, 14]);
```

[13, 14] is an array of product ids that are the cross sells.

To get the product id for a given product from our SKU, you can use:

wc_get_product_id_by_sku

Comment: I have tried your code but it seem working with up-sell product. not working with crossell product.

Comment: @huykon225, my cross sells are working, maybe it is something else.  please provide your code?